# Use class object with include file

Tags: php, class, object, include

I have 4 files; myclass.php, header.php, index.php and footer.php

Inside myclass.php i have the follow code:

```
class MyClass{
public function someFunction(){
return "OK";
}
}
```

In header.php have the follow code:

```
<?php include('myclass.php');
$Obj = new MyClass();
?>
some code ...
```

In index.php have follow code:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<?php echo $Obj->someFunction();
some code and html ...
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

And footer.php have:

```
some html code.
```

The echo don't print the "OK".

How i can solve?

Comment: Have you checked the source code? Maybe you don't see it in the browser due to some invalid html.

Comment: @MaximeLaunois fixed here, but code is Ok.  Log error says: Undefined variable Obj in index.php

Comment: Please show your actual code instead of pseudo-code that probably doesn't reflect what is actually happening.

Comment: Your code works correctly for me, both by using CLI and development server. Perhaps some code is overwriting or deleting your `$Obj` variable. Or your `$Obj` is used in a function; if so you need to add `global $Obj` at the start of the function.